Unattended login to show SharePoint Pages
I have a digital signage display that needs to show content from Microsoft 365 services like SharePoint pages, Excel files, and Word documents.
The display operates unattended and has no keyboard or mouse, so users cannot log in on-site.
Is it possible to fully automate a login via client-side certificates (MS Entra CBA), or are there other methods?

You can automate login to SharePoint pages using Microsoft Entra certificate-based authentication (CBA). This method allows users to authenticate directly with X.509 certificates against their Microsoft Entra ID, which can be configured to support unattended scenarios.
To implement this, you would need to ensure that the digital signage display is joined to Microsoft Entra ID and that the necessary CBA configurations are set up in your tenant. Once configured, the display can use the client-side certificate for authentication without requiring user interaction.
References:
Passwordless authentication with Microsoft Entra ID
Windows smart card sign-in using Microsoft Entra certificate-based authentication
Passwordless authentication options for Microsoft Entra ID

Yes, absolutely. You'd need to register an Entra Id application (or create application registration) in the AAD of the same tenant where your Microsoft 365. Then provide Application (not delegated) API permissions to your app depending on your needs (e.g. Sites.Read.All or Sites.Selected) and configure secret or certificate. Then you can use App Id (client id) and secret/certificate to authenticate to m365 as application (unattended).
References:

Microsoft Graph and app-only authentication
Sites.Selected API permissions for SharePoint access

